# Function to go forward one directory, if possible?

Tags: shell-script, command-line, scripting, zsh

I use below code snippet (by pressing `alt-h`), to go backward one level of current directory.

```
up-dir() { 
  cd ".."
  zle reset-prompt 
}
zle -N up-dir
bindkey "^[h" up-dir
```

I want similar functionality to map `alt-b` to go forward one level, if `cd -` is possible. If I don't have anything to go forward I shouldn't be able to.

I use zsh 5.8.

Comment: Please edit question to make it clear: Are you looking for an undo, or to go forward if there is only one option, or something else?

Comment: I might need both. but this is obvious about go forward case.

Comment: Please **edit question** to make it **clear**: Are you looking for an undo, or to go forward if there is only one option, or something else?

Comment: Have you tried TAB key. <kbd>.</kbd> <kbd>TAB</kbd>

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you mean by “forward one level”? Do you want the key binding to invoke `cd -`? It's almost always possible (unless the directory has been deleted), and if it isn't possible it won't do anything anyway.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```bsh
down-dir() {
  if [[ $OLDPWD == "$PWD"* ]]; then
    cd -
  else
    echo "previous dir is not below the current dir"
  fi
}
```

Comment: Is this go forward case only? `cd -` would not able to `undo` because of `if [[ $OLDPWD == "$PWD"* ]]` I assume.

Comment: Yes, that's right

Comment: @Tuyen, Stéphane Chazelas is very much a zsh expert, so take a close look at this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
up-dir() {
  set -o localoptions -o pushdsilent
  [[ $PWD != / ]] && pushd .. && zle reset-prompt
}

undo-up-dir() {
  set -o localoptions -o pushdsilent

  # pop a directory only if the current working directory matches
  # the "h"ead of the top ([1]) of the directory stack:
  [[ $dirstack[1]:h = $PWD ]] && popd && zle reset-prompt
}

zle -N up-dir
zle -N undo-up-dir
bindkey '^[h' up-dir
bindkey '^[b' undo-up-dir
```

Note the `&&`s to make sure we return a non-zero exit status (which should trigger a beep or other form of failure feedback) when the directory is not changed.

You could also extend that `undo-up-dir` so that when it can't undo anymore, it could still look whether there's exactly one directory in the current directory and go into it:

```
down-dir() {
  set -o localoptions -o pushdsilent

  # pop a directory only if the current working directory matches
  # the "h"ead of the top ([1]) of the directory stack:
  if [[ $dirstack[1]:h = $PWD ]]; then
    popd
  else
    local -a dirs
    dirs=(./*(N/Y2))
    (($#dirs)) || dirs=(./*(ND/Y2)) # try including hidden ones
    (($#dirs)) || dirs=(./*(N-/Y2)) # try including symlinks to dirs
    (($#dirs)) || dirs=(./*(DN-/Y2)) # symlinks and hidden included
    (($#dirs == 1)) && cd $dirs
  fi && zle reset-prompt
}
```